# Is there anyway that the user don't have to be clearing the cache every time there is a change in the website?

Tags: php, wordpress, w3-total-cache

I am using W3 Total Cache plugin in my web site. Is there anyway that the user doesn't have to clear the cache every time there is a change in the website?

Comment: Improved grammar.

Answer (score 0):

You just disable the plugin and disbale the caheche create option in the wordpress plugin

Answer (score 0):

You will have to add a function to the functions.php file of your theme.

```
function vs_delete_w3tc_cache($post_id ){
if ( function_exists( 'w3tc_pgcache_flush_post' ) ) 
 { 
   w3tc_pgcache_flush_post($post_id); 
 }
}
add_action( 'save_post', 'vs_delete_w3tc_cache' );
```

This should delete the cache for that post/page.